# .translated function not working in Godot / best way to change position of bone

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm working on a program in Godot using Gdscript, and I ran into a problem when trying to use the `Transform.translated(Vector3)` function. My code is supposed to move a bone to (0,0,0) by translating it by its current coordinates but with negative sign. Example: (1,2,3) would be translated by (-1,-2,-3) so it would end up at (0,0,0). For some reason when I do this, the end position of the bone is not (0,0,0), but some other coordinate. In the Godot documents, it says the .translated function is "relative to the transform's basis vectors", so maybe that's why? Also if there is a better way to change a bones position than using the `Transform.translated(Vector3)` function that would be helpful too. Thanks!

My Code:

```
            bonePose = skel.get_bone_global_pose(bone)
            var globalBonePose = skel.to_global(bonePose.origin)
            translateVector = -globalBonePose
            var newPose = bonePose.translated(translateVector)
            skel.set_bone_pose(bone, newPose)
```

Code Output / Results:

bonePose (the original position of the bone) is around (-0.82,0.49,0.50)

translateVector (the amount the bone will be translated) is around (0.82,-0.49,-0.50)

newPose (the final position of the bone -- should be [0,0,0]) is around (0.82,-0.66,-0.46). Even when I call `skel.to_global(newPose.origin)` to see the global coordinates, it's (-0.76,0.44,0.42), which is not (0,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Godot a `Transform` is composed of a `basis` (a `Basis`) and an `origin` (a `Vector3`). Where the `origin` handles the translation part of the transform, and the `Basis` the rest.

A `Basis` is the set of vectors that define the coordinate system. There is a vector that defines the `x` axis, another for the `y` axis, and another for the `z` axis. And this is the way Godot will encode rotation and scaling transformations.

When the documentation says "relative to the transform's basis vectors" it means the `Basis` will be applied to the vector you pass in. Thus, in your case, you are getting a translation on the local space of the bone. Which implies that if the bone is rotated or scaled (or something like that), that will affect the translation.

If you don't want to deal with rotation, scaling, et.al. I suggest you work with the `origin` of the `Transform` instead.

If you have a `Transform` and you want another that is otherwise equal but located at `(0, 0, 0)`, you do this:

```
var new_transform = Transform(transform.basis, Vector.ZERO)
```

Or replace `Vector.ZERO` with whatever origin you want to give the new transform.

---

I also need to remind you that `get_bone_global_pose` and `set_bone_pose` do not operate on the same thing. On one hand `set_bone_pose` is relative to the parent bone, on the other `get_bone_global_pose` is relative to the `Skeleton`. Thus, I suggest you use `set_bone_global_pose_override` instead.

---

The final piece you need is the opposite of `Spatial.to_global`. Because setting the pose like as follows…

```
bonePose = skel.get_bone_global_pose(bone)
var newPose = Transform(bonePose.basis, Vector.ZERO)
skel.set_bone_global_pose_override(bone, newPose, 1.0)
```

… Would place it at the origin of the `Skeleton`.

Well, the opposite of `Spatial.to_global` is `Spatial.to_local`, and you would use it like this:

```
bonePose = skel.get_bone_global_pose(bone)
var newPose = Transform(bonePose.basis, skel.to_local(Vector.ZERO))
skel.set_bone_global_pose_override(bone, newPose, 1.0)
```

Here `skel.to_local(Vector.ZERO)` should give the origin of the world relative to the `Skeleton`. And given that `set_bone_global_pose_override` wants a `Transform` relative to the `Skeleton`, the result should be that the bone is placed at the origin of the world. *With its rotation and scaling preserved.*

Comment: When running `var newPose = Transform.new(bonePose.Basis, skel.to_local(Vector.ZERO))` there is an error message that says "Static constant 'new' not present in built-in type Transform". I tried removing `.new`, but then I recieved a new error message saying "Invalid get Index 'Basis' (on base: 'Transform').

Comment: @DB Right, that is on me. Don't use `.new`, and the property is `basis` (lower caps). I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One more thing, `skel.set_bone_global_pose_override(bone, newPose)` gave an error message saying it needs a third argument. When I looked on the docs it says there are actually four, `void set_bone_global_pose_override ( int bone_idx, Transform pose, float amount, bool persistent=false )`. Do you know what the last two are used for?

Comment: @DB I see, and what they do isn't documented. I went and look at the source to figure that one, here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/3d/skeleton.cpp#L292 - So: `amount` will blend the poses. `amount = 0` means leave the original pose, and `amount = 1` mean apply the override pose, and you can use numbers in between which result in an interpolation. I'll put `1` on the answer. As per `persistent`, it tells Godot if it should keep about the override after applied or not. If the override is persistent then when the skeleton moves afterwards, it does not change the override.